# Keep your distance other options

Tags: phrase-choice

Do all of these sound natural?

1. "Keep distance."
2. "Keep a safe distance."
3. "Keep social distance."
4. "Keep two meters distance."
5. "Keep a two-meter distance."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your question, yes they sound natural and correct with the exception of the third one.

An alternative to these statements may be with the help of the word: [maintain](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk02YBfy9GW8urKSVTdNm53jD7Er0LA%3A1601036829558&ei=HeJtX8jLIcmY4-EPyrWN-AE&q=maintain%20meaning&oq=main&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgkIABBDEEYQ-QEyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyCAgAELEDEIMBMgQILhBDOgcIIxDqAhAnOgQIIxAnOgQILhAnOgcILhAnEJMCOgUIABCRAjoLCC4QsQMQxwEQowI6DgguELEDEIMBEMcBEKMCOgUIABCxA1DH9AFYo_gBYPX_AWgBcAF4AIABtwGIAZEFkgEDMC40mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdperABCsABAQ&sclient=psy-ab).

> Maintain distance
>
> Maintain a safe distance
>
> Maintain social distance/distancing.
>
> Maintain two metres distance.
>
> Maintain a two-metre distance.

Answer (score 1):

> "Keep distance."

> "Keep social distance."

These don't sound right to me.  "Keep your distance from others" or "Keep your distance" would be much better.

> "Keep a safe distance."

This is correct.

> "Keep two meters distance."

It should really be *two meters' distance* with an apostrophe, although many native speakers will miss that.  (In British English we write *two metres' distance*, i.e. "metre" rather than "meter".)

Better would be "Keep two meters' distance from others", but the shorter version would be understood.

> "Keep a two-meter distance."

Again, "keep a two-meter distance form others" would be better, but the shorter version would be understood (and acceptable on signage) in the context of the present crisis.

Comment: Regarding the hyphen, is it also written with a hyphen "Keep two-meters distance"?

Comment: I corrected my answer a few moments before I saw your question. I used the term "hyphen" by mistake.  I actually meant that there should strictly speaking be an apostrophe (') in "Keep two metres' distance" - not a hyphen.  (There should be a hyphen in "Keep a two-metre distance".  There is no hyphen is "two metres' distance".)